# how to access the api and map the data?

Tags: reactjs

I can't access the api and map the data.
I don't know how to set the response correctly.
nor how to enter the properties of the object
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

file newlist:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getNews } from '../../api/drupalAPI'


export const NewsList = () => {
   
    const [newsList, setNewsList] = useState()

    const fetchNewsList = async () => {
            getNews().then((response)=>{
                setNewsList(JSON.stringify(response));
            }).catch ( (error)  => {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            });
        }
      
 

    useEffect (() => {
        fetchNewsList();  
    }, []);

   return (
        <div>
            {
                newsList.map(news => (
                   
                        <div>{news.title}</div>
                   
                ))
            }
        </div>
   ); 
}

file api

import {News} from '@icofcv/common';
import store from '../store';

function getHeaders() {
    let headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      };

    if (store.getState().session.credentials) {
        headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${store.getState().session.credentials.accessToken}`;
    }

    return headers;
}

export async function getNews(): Promise<News[]>  { 
            const filter = {
              "offset": 0,
              "limit": 100,
              "skip": 0,
              "fields": {
                "id": true,
                "title": true,
                "creationDate": true,
                "enabled": true
              }
            };
      
            const response = await fetch('/news?filter='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filter)), {
              method: "GET",
              headers: getHeaders()
            });

            const data = await response.json();

            if (response.ok) {
                return data;
            }
            else {
                return Promise.reject(response.status);
            }

  }
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(response)` will convert the result to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to [stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) the result. set the result Directly

```
setNewsList(response);
```